# Is it possible to use brunch without Git?

Tags: brunch

We're trying to run the command

```
brunch new MySkeleton MyProject
```

this results in the error

```
02 Jul 14:56:30 - error: Error: npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
```

We don't use git, and would prefer to avoid switching source control systems right now.  Is it possible to use brunch without git?

`MySkeleton` is stored in a subdirectory of the current directory. Likewise, the idea is to create `MyProject` in a subdirectory.  The same error occurs with full paths, e.g. /JSapps/MySkeleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The skeleton we're using contains references to other brunch pieces which live in github. So it seems that while brunch itself doesn't intrinsically require git, the fact that the brunch ecosystem is hosted in github makes the *installation* of a git a de-facto requirement.

But, just because brunch uses git, that doesn't mean we're forced to use it for source control.  (Though it does mean we end up with a bunch of .git* files in our source control, which does seems rather "untidy")

Answer (score -1):

`brunch new MyProject MySkeleton`

Comment: Reversing the order like that changes the message to `error: Error: Directory 'MySkeleton' is already an npm project` which is what you'd expect.  Installing git allows the command to complete with the args in the original ordering. Which still leaves the question, is git a requirement for using brunch?